# authentication and authorization with angular

Tags: angularjs, authentication

I want to make an admin section with angular 
not sure how to tackle it

1) should i go for authentication and authorization via angular

2) or house my angular app inside a PHP/ROR application which will take care of authentication

if 1) then what is the best practice or style that you guys recommend

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need, the authentication should be server side however you manage it in angular with a service:

https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec

Answer (score 0):

The authentication and authorization should be handled by a *server controller* with appropriate pages for login and register. Ideally you may want to have the admin sections to be all handled in a *single* controller so you can protect them against unauthorized access at a controller level.

On the angular side you will want to receive the authentication tokens and save them in local storage.

Since you mentioned a PHP server, [Here](https://github.com/rameshpa/angular-cakephp-auth) is a small project I wrote for angular authentication against a Cake PHP server. The [Readme](https://github.com/rameshpa/angular-cakephp-auth/blob/master/README.md) has the basic concepts